Numbered paragraphs with same text indetation on differrent levels (for legal clauses)
I'm trying to create a legal document with clauses and sub-clauses essentially I want it to look like this:

I have tried to get this effect using enumitem like so:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Define the environment for legal clauses
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[legal,1]{%
label=\arabic*, 
ref=\arabic*, 
itemindent=0em, 
leftmargin=3em, 
labelsep=!, 
itemsep=0pt,%0.5em, 
align=left
}
%
\setlist[legal,2]{%
label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*, 
ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*, 
itemindent=0em, 
listparindent=0em, 
leftmargin=3em, 
labelsep=!, 
itemsep=0pt,%0.5em, 
align=left, 
left=-3em}
%
\setlist[legal,3]{%
label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*, 
ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*, 
left=0em, 
labelsep=1em, 
itemsep=0.5em, 
align=left
}


\begin{document}
\begin{legal}
    \item This is the first clause.
    \item This Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
        \begin{legal}
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros. Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
            \item This is another sub-clause of the second clause.
                \begin{legal}
                    \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque lobortis justo enim, a condimentum massa tempor eu. Ut quis nulla a quam pretium eleifend nec eu nisl. Nam cursus porttitor eros, sed luctus ligula convallis quis.
                    \item This is another sub-sub-clause of the second sub-clause.
                \end{legal}
            \item This is a third sub-clause of the second clause.
        \end{legal}
    \item This is the third clause.
\end{legal}
\end{document}

But the result is like this:

This is nearly what I want, but I'm finding it virtually impossible to understand what all the indentation options do. Can anyone help me get the indentation right? At this stage the bolding and underlining of the first level is a "nice-to-have" not something I'm overly concerned about. It's the indentation I want to match.
P.s. I am aware of scrjura from KOMA-Scripts, but I want to use this in an existing custom document class.

Just a note because of your PS: scrjura is not limited to be used with KOMA-Script classes. The scrjura successor contract can be used with other classes, too. However, I'm not sure, that one of them would be a package you are searching for. Your image indeed looks more like an enumerate.

@cabohah, I actually tried contract, but it didn't work and the author explicitly advises for users to wait until it's packaged for your distribution. Regarding scrjura, I didn't realise it worked with other classes, I also didn't really like how it looked, which as you point out, isn't that similar to what I'm looking for.

Off-topic: I've tested contract and it works, e.g., with article. And both, MiKTeX and TeX Live already provide it. So if you are using MiKTeX maybe you need to reload the repository so be able to install it. If you are using TeX Live you are maybe using an old TeX Live, not TeX Live 2024 and could consider to install TeX Live 2024. Or are you using Overleaf? Maybe the TeX Live of Overleaf it too old and indeed does not provide the package.

I'm using TexLive 2021.20220204-1 which is what comes with my current Mint Linux distribution, I'm unlikely to change just for this.

Ah, see. So it is not a general problem but a problem of using an old TeX Live version. Thanks for note.

Maybe the simplest is to play with left=<labelindent>  .. <leftmargin>. Quoting the manual of the enumitem package (section 3.2, Horizontal spacing of labels)

You may regard it as a sort or “rule” with two tab stops: the start of the label and the start of the text (both with relation to the normal side margin)

So, try
left= 0pt .. 3em,

for legal,1,
left= -3em .. 0pt,

for legal,2, and
left= 0pt .. 3em,

for legal,3.
Example :
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Define the environment for legal clauses
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{3}

\setlist[legal,1]{%
  label=\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic*,
  left= 0pt .. 3em,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0pt,%0.5em,
}

\setlist[legal,2]{%
  label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic*,
  left= -3em .. 0pt,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0pt,%0.5em,
}

\setlist[legal,3]{%
  label=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*,
  ref=\arabic{legali}.\arabic{legalii}.\arabic*,
  left= 0pt .. 3em,
  align=left,
  itemsep=0.5em,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{legal}
 \item This is the first clause.
 \item This Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros.
  Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum
  molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu
  dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa, ut
  laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus tincidunt
  vestibulum at ac elit.
  \begin{legal}
   \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Praesent porttitor arcu luctus, imperdiet urna iaculis, mattis eros.
    Pellentesque iaculis odio vel nisl ullamcorper, nec faucibus ipsum
    molestie. Sed dictum nisl non aliquet porttitor. Etiam vulputate arcu
    dignissim, finibus sem et, viverra nisl. Aenean luctus congue massa,
    ut laoreet metus ornare in. Nunc fermentum nisi imperdiet lectus
    tincidunt vestibulum at ac elit.
   \item This is another sub-clause of the second clause.
    \begin{legal}
     \item In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur mattis elit
      sit amet justo luctus vestibulum. In hac habitasse platea
      dictumst. Pellentesque lobortis justo enim, a condimentum
      massa tempor eu. Ut quis nulla a quam pretium eleifend nec eu
      nisl. Nam cursus porttitor eros, sed luctus ligula
      convallis quis.
     \item This is another sub-sub-clause of the second sub-clause.
    \end{legal}
   \item This is a third sub-clause of the second clause.
  \end{legal}
 \item This is the third clause.
\end{legal}

\end{document}



lovely, thanks!

Although unfortunately I've noticed once you get to clause 10, extra indentation is added to the text which I've added another question about here
